# Stream output with Jenkins Pipeline + Docker/VM

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using Jenkins Pipeline for my jobs and they run either in a Docker container or a VM.

The problem is that I have some tasks that last some time and I would like to stream the output of the commands in the console while the job is running.

Indeed, in the groovy script, I do this kind of stuff:

```
 stage('test') {
  TEST = sh (
     script: '''cd $WORKSPACE
                make test
             ''',
     returnStdout: true
  ).trim()
  echo "TEST: ${TEST}"
}
```

With these lines, the output is printed in the job console only after the command has finished. If "make test" takes a long time, that's not great...

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all the code and it will do what you want. :)

```
stage('test') {
  sh (
    '''cd $WORKSPACE
        make test
    '''
  )
}
```